# One intersectionObserver to observe many elements or one intersectionObserver per element

Tags: javascript, performance, intersection-observer

We have a few CustomElements in our page and some of them have an IntersectionObserver relative to the viewport observing them. That number might be increasing as the designer seems to like intersection animations.

Will that lead to performance issues? Is it better to have one IntersectionObserver that observes all elements or many IntersectionObservers that only observe one element?

Comment: That is very hard to answer and guess and depends on a lot of factors like DOM size, how often these animations happen, how users use the site, what browsers you support and more factors. In general I would __guess__ that for up to 10-20 elements adding individual observers is preferable to observing a shared root and over that it's better being with one although really - I wouldn't expect it to be a huge issue anyway regardless.

Comment: I can refer you to the code that does the actual work in Chromium, but I don't think that would help you answer your question - honestly it should be fast enough unless you're doing it to hundreds of elements at once.

Comment: See https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3954-intersectionobserver-api-performance-many-vs-shared-in-angular-11-0-5.htm - it says that one can be much faster.

Comment: Thank you. I think we ended doing just that. It was 2 years ago :P

Answer (score 4):

As already stated, there are a lot of factors to consider!

I made the below library specifically for a media heavy site.  A normal user session might setup and teardown > 1000 observers.

Since everything happens off the main thread it is hard to observer memory usage as show [here](https://github.com/snewcomer/raf-pool#normal).  However, metrics showed us one IntersectionObserver for all the elements gave users an overall improvement. This package should be relatively easy to use!

https://github.com/snewcomer/intersection-observer-admin