# How do I use a single IntersectionObserver to perform unique callbacks per observed element?

Tags: javascript, html, oop, intersection-observer

I need to know out when dozens of HTMLElements are inside or outside of the viewport when scrolling down the page. So I'm using the [`IntersectionObserver API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to create several instances of a `VisibilityHelper` class, each one with its own IntersectionObserver. With this helper class, I can detect when any HTMLElement is 50% visible or hidden:

### Working demo:

```js
// Create helper class
class VisibilityHelper {
  constructor(htmlElem, hiddenCallback, visibleCallback) {
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver((entities) => {
      const ratio = entities[0].intersectionRatio;
      if (ratio <= 0.0) {
        hiddenCallback();
      } else if (ratio >= 0.5) {
        visibleCallback();
      }
    }, {threshold: [0.0, 0.5]});

    this.observer.observe(htmlElem);
  }
}

// Get elements
const headerElem = document.getElementById("header");
const footerElem = document.getElementById("footer");

// Use helper class to know whether visible or hidden
const headerViz = new VisibilityHelper(
  headerElem,
  () => {console.log('header is hidden')},
  () => {console.log('header is visible')},
);
const footerViz = new VisibilityHelper(
  footerElem,
  () => {console.log('footer is hidden')},
  () => {console.log('footer is visible')},
);
```

```css
#page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #fff);
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f90;
  text-align: center;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #09f;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
  Header
  </div>


  <div id="footer">
  Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that my demo above creates one `IntersectionObserver` for each HTMLElement that needs to be watched. I need to use this on 100 elements, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55867849/one-intersectionobserver-to-observe-many-elements-or-one-intersectionobserver-pe) indicates that we should only use **one** `IntersectionObserver` per page for performance reasons. Secondly, [the API also suggests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) that one observer can be used to watch several elements, since the callback will give you a list of entries.

How would you use a single `IntersectionObserver` to watch multiple `htmlElements` and trigger unique hidden/visible callbacks for each element?

Comment: This is a hard one, because, as you mentioned, you have unique callbacks for different elements you are observing. I found this on SO that might help - essentially using passed entry data attributes to change the callback: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460010/how-to-call-different-functions-for-different-targets-using-an-intersection-obse

Answer (score 1):

You can define a callback mapping between your target elements and their visibility state. Then inside of your `IntersectionObserver` callback, use the [`IntersectionObserverEntry.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/target) to read the `id` and invoke the associated callback from the map based on the visibility state of `visible` or `hidden`.

Here is a simplified approach based on your example. The gist of the approach is defining the `callbacks` map and reading the `target` from the `IntersectionObserverEntry`:

```js
// Create helper class
class VisibilityHelper {
  constructor(htmlElems, callbacks) {
this.callbacks = callbacks;
this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  (entities) => {
    const ratio = entities[0].intersectionRatio;
    const target = entities[0].target;

    if (ratio <= 0.0) {
      this.callbacks[target.id].hidden();
    } else if (ratio >= 0.5) {
      this.callbacks[target.id].visible();
    }
  },
  { threshold: [0.0, 0.5] }
);

htmlElems.forEach((elem) => this.observer.observe(elem));
  }
}

// Get elements
const headerElem = document.getElementById("header");
const footerElem = document.getElementById("footer");

// Use helper class to know whether visible or hidden
const helper = new VisibilityHelper([headerElem, footerElem], {
  header: {
visible: () => console.log("header is visible"),
hidden: () => console.log("header is hidden"),
  },
  footer: {
visible: () => console.log("footer is visible"),
hidden: () => console.log("footer is hidden"),
  },
});
```

```css
#page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1500px;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #fff);
}
#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f90;
  text-align: center;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #09f;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
  Header
  </div>


  <div id="footer">
  Footer
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use a similar approach if you want to loop over the entire array of `entities` instead of just considering the first `entities[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see what you're trying to do, using the ID. I guess this is my fault for using IDs in the example, but I don't necessarily have unique IDs per element. I guess I could [create custom `data` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead, but it feels a bit hacky. I was hoping the `IntersectionObserver` had a more object-oriented approach in mind that I didn't know about.

Comment: You need some way to reference the HTML elements that will be observed, whether it be `id`, `class`, or `data-` attributes. Depending on your requirements the callbacks associated with each HTML element can be defined within the `IntersectionObserver` callback if that is what you mean by `more object-oriented approach`.